Why do I need to define the Git origin for each PyCharm project under a common Git root?
I have a directory under Git control, where subdirectories are PyCharm projects.
When I try to commit and push a new project PyCharm requires the Git origin URL, which it could normally retrieve from the directory structure, as the Git CLI does.
So, why is PyCharm doing this? Am I missing something?
